# Home page not fully rendered on godady

Tags: 7, configuration

I uploaded a website to a Godaddy shared hosing account, but the home page never get fully render.

I checked the PHP version and the extensions, also checked the file/folder permissions.

The website reports page has no errors or warnings.

All other pages are working perfectly including the admin pages, FYI i uploaded the website on another server and it's working without that issue,

Here are the PHP extensions:
[image]

And the PHP options:
[image]

Any advice?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the godaddy error logs? it looks like you need at least the deluxe package to see the logs. https://www.godaddy.com/help/working-with-error-logs-1197

Comment: ask go daddy for help?

Comment: The error logs says nothing about this issue @Weboide

Comment: I asked, all they did for me is adding a PHP info file  @NoSssweat

Comment: I think this issue somehow related to cache, when i uploaded un-empty cache database the home page rendered completely, but when i cleared the cache the issue start appear again, any thoughts?

Comment: Not specifically, this just means that the page building/processing part or even anything after that is where lies the problem. Getting logs would be your best bet to resolve this.